# Pointwise convergence and $L^2$ convergence.

Tags: functional-analysis, pointwise-convergence

Let $\lbrace f_n \rbrace$ be a sequence of functions in $L^2([a,b])$ for some real closed interval $[a,b]$. In general, if $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise, does the sequence also converge in norm?

If the sequence is bounded, it is true by DCT. Also, it is easy to find a counter example in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. But is it true in general in $L^2([a,b])$? I believe it is not, but I have not been able to build a counter example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider $f_n:=n\mathbf1_{\{0\le x\le\frac1n\}}$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: If you mean $f_n(x) = n \chi_{[0,1/n]}(x)$ this function is not in $L^2([0,1])$.

Comment: Why not?$\vphantom{???}$

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. It is. Thanks for your answer :)